# Deducing distribution of gaps between events (primes) from probability of events?

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers

If the probability of an integer belonging to an arbitrary class $\mathbb{P}$ is $P(n)$, we can work out, or estimate, things like the expected number of integers of that class in a given number range, eg $\sum_1^N P(n) dn$.

**Question:** Can we use the probability $P(n)$ to work out the distribution of the gaps between integers of that class in a given number range?

---

**Note:**

Although this question is about any probability $P(n)$, it is motivated by the primes $\mathbb{P}$ and the distribution of prime gaps, but this shouldn't distract from the more general question.

The log-count of prime gaps is a linear function of the gap size, very approximately. This tells us the primes occur "randomly" because if they didn't, the distribution of gaps would be of a different form. **(Is this correct?)**

More specific questions are:

- if the probability of an integer being of class $\mathbb{P}$ was Gaussian or Poisson, what would this mean for the distribution of gaps?
- what if the probability was uniform, like the probability of a number being even or odd?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maier%27s_theorem

Comment: it looks like this isn't a trivial question ... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9220/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-euclidean-distance-between-two-normally-distribu

Comment: nothing about the primes is really trivial